# monthly breakdown of table data, date stored as epoch time

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a mysql table that contains a date field in epoch time format. I need to count how many rows I have for each calendar month of the year. I don't even know where to start. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(mycolumn)) AS yr,
        MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(mycolumn)) AS mon,
        COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        yr, mon
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with something like this:

```
select count(1) from table group by month(<your timestamp column>)
```